# C# - MSBuild reference - Copy to CopyToOutputDirectory all items of <itemGroup>

Tags: c#, msbuild, itemgroup

I'm trying to copy all files in a project to an output directory.

Right now I've unloaded my process and in my "TestProject.csproj" I have these options for the item I'd like to copy:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TEST\file1.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="TEST\file2.xml" >
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

What i want is to be able to copy all  items in that  to  folder, included other that gonna be added later on ( ...file3.xml, file4.xml ).

I don't want to be forced to manually add to every file the "PreserveNewest" behavior, but I would like to use some sort of "post-compile option" to make it work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify default item metadata with [item definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-definitions?view=vs-2019):

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This would apply as a default to all `Content` items. You should be able to constrain this to only XML files by using a condition:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory Condition="'%(Content.Extension)'=='.xml'">PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: Worked. I've seen that for <ItemDefinitionGroup> there's no attribute for a custom OutputDirectory. It's possbile to use the same approach to define a custom outputPath?

Comment: I think the metadata for where to copy that item is `TargetPath`, which usually is determined during build by other targets, but it's possible that you can set it yourself.